# Compiling c# at runtime throws some errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, monodevelop

I am attempting to compile some c# code from a string in unity however I am getting this error when running the code

What should be happening is in the console i Should see "Working" printed every frame but instead as soon as you start up the scene these 2 errors immediatly popup

**Error 1:**

> Too many characters in character literal
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   WebSharp:Compile() (at Assets/Scripts/WebSharp.cs:54)
>   WebSharp:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/WebSharp.cs:17)

**Error 2:**

> Unexpected symbol '
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   WebSharp:Compile() (at Assets/Scripts/WebSharp.cs:54)
>   WebSharp:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/WebSharp.cs:17)

Full Class Code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public class WebSharp : MonoBehaviour {

    protected Assembly generatedAssembly;
    private Type myScriptType = null;
    private object myScriptInstance = null;

    private void Start(){
        Compile ();
    }

    private string scriptText = "" +
        "using UnityEngine; " +
        "public class TestScript: MonoBehavior{" +
        "private void Update(){" +
        "Debug.Log('Working');" +
        "}" +
        "}";

    private void Update(){
        if (myScriptType == null || myScriptInstance == null) {
            return;
        }

        //Run the scripts update function
        myScriptType.InvokeMember ("Update", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, myScriptInstance, null);
    }

    private void Compile(){
        try{
            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
            compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize /warn:0";
            compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
            compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
            compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");

            CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams,scriptText);

            if(results.Errors.Count > 0){
                foreach(CompilerError error in results.Errors){
                    Debug.Log(error.ErrorText);
                }
            }else{
                generatedAssembly = results.CompiledAssembly;

                if(generatedAssembly != null){
                    myScriptType = generatedAssembly.GetType("TestScript");

                    myScriptInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myScriptType);

                    Debug.LogAssertion("Success");
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Debug.LogError (e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Working'` is not a valid string inside `scripttext`. You need double quotes for a string literal. Use \ to escape the double quotes, e.g. `\"Working\"`

Comment: that worked! thx

Answer (score 0):

`'Working'` is not a valid string inside `scripttext`. You need double quotes for a string literal. Use \ to escape the double quotes, e.g. `\"Working\"`